# Job running even though not all rules evaluate to true

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

The [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#complex-rules) say "The rule evaluates to true only when *all* included keywords evaluate to true". But in my case when I change and push a file not included in my `changes` keyword file list, the job runs.

```yaml
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - tag

.files: &files
  - .gitlab-ci.yml
  - source/**/*

only_changes:
  extends: .my-job
  script:
    - echo "job runs"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      changes: *files
```

I push a commit where I only change some markdown file outside of `source/` and yet the `only_changes` job still runs. What am I not getting? Is this a mistake in the docs and it should say the job runs if *any* of the rules evaluates to true?

Comment: For merge request pipelines, it evaluates all changes between the source and target branch, not just the last commit or push. There are also some cases where `changes:` evaluates to true irrespective of the changes actually made, such as limitations of the number of files in the repo, or if the pipeline is not a branch or MR pipeline (e.g., tag pipelines, schedules, etc.). It would be important to know if any of those situations apply in this case.